# Override XDocument.Load Request Headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I am currently using Google's Finance API to pull stock information. (Yes I know it is deprecated and may be discontinued soon).

When I load the XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=ticker");
```

I am returning a 503 (probably due to to many requests in a given time period.

Is there anyway I can override the request headers sent to more or less mimic a user agent header from chrome?

Comment: So this looks like its working again - The problem I ran into stemmed from running Apache Benchmark using 10k concurrent requests which led to my temporary blockage by Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can override the request headers sent to more or less mimic a user agent header from chrome?

The simplest approach is probably not to use the overload that takes a URL in that case. Instead, create a `WebRequest` which has all the headers and any other customizations you want, get the response, and pass the response stream to [`XDocument.Load(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349.aspx).